# Bulk load in hbase using pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have a log file in HDFS which needs to be parsed and put in a Hbase table.

I want to do this using PIG .

How can i go about it.Pig script should parse the logs and then put in Hbase?

Answer (score 0):

The pig script would be (assuming tab is your data separator in log file):

> ```
> A= load '/home/log.txt' using PigStorage('\t') as (one:chararray,two:chararray,three:chararray,four:chararray);
>
> STORE A INTO 'hbase://table1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('P:one,P:two,S:three,S:four');
> ```

Comment: hi 
my fields are not tab delimited i need to write regex for field extraction how can i do that?

Comment: The PigStroage (r7.0 ) API supports using regex as delimiter identifier : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html